# Blogger Static Pages Display Content on Half of the Page

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, blogger

This page https://www.neuroscientia.com/p/iq.html only displays content in half of the page. It is a static page like other static pages such as ABOUT US, CONTACT US etc and all these pages do display their content in only half of the page while leaving the other half blank on all screen sizes. I have tweaked my HTML source code and couldn't get what's causing this.

I am using a responsive template, set Media screens, view point already. So I'm confused why this error should occur.

The blog is hosted on Blogger. Please I need your help on displaying the content on the full screen for all devices.

Comment: `.blog-posts-wrapper {
    float: left;
    width: 48%;
    margin-right: 1.5%;
}`

Your wrapper has a width of 48%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a class stoping the content width:

```
.blog-posts-wrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
  margin-right: 1.5%;
}
```

Change it to :

```
.blog-posts-wrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 1.5%;
}
```