# Blogger Blog Archive Displays on Half of the Page on Mobile Screens

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, blogger

This Blogger blog archive search results like https://www.neuroscientia.com/2018/08/ only display the posts in half of the page while leaving the other half blank on especially on mobile screen sizes. I have tweaked my HTML source code and couldn't get what's causing this.

I am using a responsive template, set Media screens, viewpoint already. So I'm confused why this error should occur.

**The similar thread I have tried:** [Blogger Static Pages Display Content on Half of the Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49776469/blogger-static-pages-display-content-on-half-of-the-page)

The blog is hosted on Blogger. Please, I need your help on displaying the Blog Archive search results list on the full screen for all devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `.blog-posts-wrapper` has `float: left`, if you want to make them stay in the center on mobile screens you have to set `float: none; margin: auto`

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .blog-posts-wrapper {
      float: none;
      margin: auto;
  }
}
```

## OR

If you want them to be full width on mobile screens set:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .blog-posts-wrapper {
      width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: when I set .blog-posts-wrapper to 100%, it uglified the whole post area by pushing the sidebars to the bottom on Laptop and Desktops.

Comment: No, you don't have to add it to the current css you have to add it as a new css rule, this is media query it will work only on mobile screens.

Comment: I have fixed it properly now by placing it right within the ]]>< (CSS area). This command did the trick: @media (max-width: 767px) {
  .blog-posts-wrapper {
      width: 100%;
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

In the Code there is this command:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 755px)
   .sidebar-wrapper1 {
      display: none;
}
```

Turn that off and the right side column wont disappear!

Or if you meant you want to make the remaining column 100% width,

```
    .blog-posts-wrapper
```

is set to

```
        width: 48%;
```

so you will need to change that to 100%.

edit:

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 755px) {
         .blog-posts-wrapper  {
             width:100%;
         }
    }
```

if it still doesnt work add change to width:100%!important;

Comment: I have tried it but didn't work. Should I simply remove the entire code? How exactly can I turn it off?

Comment: Oh err, which part of the answer did you need and try? the changing to 100%?

Comment: yes. The changing to 100% affected the entire post in laptop and bigger screens. It just pushes the two sidebars to the bottom.

Comment: I would like to see the positive changes on my Samsung Galaxy S5 screen and want to effect the BlogArchive. Archive such as posts in October 2017 https://www.neuroscientia.com/2017/10/